# Visual Studio - Change NuGet's output directory for temporary files

Tags: c#, .net, xml, visual-studio, msbuild

Currently, it seems that the default behavior of a VS project is that NuGet-managed dependencies have intermediate files made by NuGet during a compile. Those files are these, in the `obj` folder:

[image]

I like being able to control the name of these output directories (as you can see with `Binary` and `Object`), and I'd like to setup my project such that the `obj` folder isn't used by NuGet to store these files. Is there a way to specify this at the project level or solution level? Maybe an MSBuild XML code snippet? Would be nice.

Any information would be appreciated.

Comment: Please create  a file named `Directory.Build.props` under your project folder and then add this in it: `<Project><PropertyGroup><MSBuildProjectExtensionsPath>$(ProjectDir)Binary\</MSBuildProjectExtensionsPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>` . With this, you can control the nuget 's output files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to specify this at the project level or solution level?
>   Maybe an MSBuild XML code snippet? Would be nice.

If you want to change these nuget restore files in another folder, you can try to use [Directly.Build.props](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019) file to control it.

**Solution**

**1)** create a file named `Directly.Build.props` in your project.

[image]

Then add these in this file:

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <MSBuildProjectExtensionsPath>$(ProjectDir)Binary\</MSBuildProjectExtensionsPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

**Note**: MSBuild Property can only be overwritten by another property. This means that you can overwrite the obj folder as a binary folder. If you want to generate two folders **Binary** and **Object**, you can try these:

**a)** When you try step 1 and then build your project, you can change the property to `$(ProjectDir)Object\` in `Directly.Build.props`file and then rebuild again. After that, you will see both of them.

**b)** do a copy task and please write these in your `xxxx.csproj` file.

```
<Target Name="CopyNugetfiles" AfterTargets="Build">
    <ItemGroup>
      <MySourceFiles Include="$(ProjectDir)Binary\*.*"/>
    </ItemGroup>
      <Copy
          SourceFiles="@(MySourceFiles)"
          DestinationFolder="$(ProjectDir)Object\"/>
  </Target>
```

Hope it could help you.

Comment: Not sure what's going on in step (b), but creating the aforementioned `Directory.Build.props` fixed it for me. Thank you!